# A trouble with the discrete product topology

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology

Consider a finite set $S=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ with the discrete topology, and moreover construct the product topological space $S^\mathbb N$ with the product topology. $S^\mathbb N$ is made by all the sequences with value in $S$. I don't understand the following affirmation that I read on my class notes

> The open subsets of $S^\mathbb N$ are of this type:
>   $$A=\{(a_n)\,:\, a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_t\; \text{are fixed for some $t\in\mathbb N$}\}$$

I disagree with the above statement, infact, for example the set $B=\{(a_n)\,:\, a_1=1\}$ is an element of the basis of the product topology, but the first element (namely $a_0$) is not fixed.

What do you think?

Comment: What do you mean by "fixed"?

Comment: for example $A=\{(a_n)\,:\, a_0=1,\, a_1=5,\, a_2=3\}$

Comment: It is true that the description you quote is not for "the open sets" but for a base for the open sets.  Your set $B$ is a finite union of sets of type $A$.

Comment: So do sets of type $A$ form a basis for the product topology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To take your specific example,
$$\left\{(a): a_1 = 1\right\} = \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}  \left\{(a): a_0 = n, a_1 = 1\right\},$$
with each of the sets in the union in the given basis. The same sort of argument shows that the sets with $a_0, \dots, a_t$ fixed are a *basis* for the open sets in $S^{\mathbb{N}}$, but you're right: the set you mention should be open in the product topology.

Comment: So the sets of type $A$ (in the quotation) form a different basis from the standard basis of the product topology.

Comment: Right: Same topology, different choice of basis.

Comment: Ok, it is clear.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a basis, and not the opens subsets